# ContentDocumentLinks subquery stopped working

Tags: soql, contentdocumentlink, subquery

I previously had this code and it was working (ContentDocumentLinks as related list subquery):

```
List<Id> recordIds = new List<Id>{'0032200000SRusR'};
List<Contact> contacts = [
        SELECT Id, Email,
        (SELECT Id, ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.Title,
                ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.FileExtension,
                ContentDocument.LatestPublishedVersion.VersionData
        FROM ContentDocumentLinks)
        FROM Contact WHERE Id IN :recordIds
];

for (Contact contact : contacts) {
    for (ContentDocumentLink link : contact.ContentDocumentLinks) {
        System.debug(link.Id);
    }
}
```

But currently it throws error:

`13:11:07:000 FATAL_ERROR AnonymousBlock: line 12, column 1`

`13:11:10:149 FATAL_ERROR System.QueryException: Implementation restriction: ContentDocumentLink requires a filter by a single Id on ContentDocumentId or LinkedEntityId using the equals operator or multiple Id's using the IN operator.`

Which is thrown on **for-loop** row `for (ContentDocumentLink link : contact.ContentDocumentLinks)`!

Workaround is clear: retrieve `ContentDocumentLink` in a separate query with `WHERE LinkedEntityId IN :recordIds`, but I was wondering, **when it stopped working? Is it a known issue? Should I raise a support case for it?**

UPDATE: the first comment is the answer, leaving the question for others who should be aware. If there are more than 1 related file attached to the record, the code will fail addressing `contact.ContentDocumentLinks`. Thank you, Sander de Jong!

Comment: As far as I can remember, querying on ContentDocumentLink has always had this restriction. Maybe there are more than 1 ContentDocumentLink objects now?

Comment: Oh, so the problem is in quantity of related records! Thank you!